# Highlight border color when both input fields match

Tags: javascript, html

I want to Highlight the border of both input fields red when they dont have the same value and Highlight them green if the match.
Also I want to write the function in Javascript and not jQuery.

HTML:

```
<form class="form">
                <hr class="verticalline">
                <input class="newpd shine" value="New Password"
                            onblur="this.value'New Password':this.value;"
                            onfocus="this.select()"
                            onclick="if (this.value=='New Password'){this.value=''; this.type='password'}">
                <input class="repeatpd shine" value="Repeat Password"
                            onblur="this.value'Repeat Password':this.value;"
                            onfocus="this.select()"
                            onclick="if (this.value=='Repeat Password'){this.value=''; this.type='password'}">
                <input id="button" type="button" value="Submit" onclick="ausgabe();">
```

Javascript:

```
/*changedpd*/
function passtrue(){
    var newpd = document.getElementsByClassName('newpd').value;
    var repeatpd = document.getElementsByClassName('repeatpd').value;
    if(newpd === repeatpd){
        document.getElementsByClassName('shine').style.border ="2px solid green";
    }else{
        document.getElementsByClassName('shine').style.border ="2px solid red";
    } 
}
function ausgabe(){
    document.getElementById('button').innerHTML = passtrue();
}
```

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` returns list of elements, not just one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getElementsByClassName` returns list of elements, not just one.

Make it

```
function passtrue(){
    var newpd = document.getElementsByClassName('newpd')[0].value;
    var repeatpd = document.getElementsByClassName('repeatpd')[0].value;
    if(newpd === repeatpd){
        document.getElementsByClassName('shine')[0].style.border ="2px solid green";
    }else{
        document.getElementsByClassName('shine')[0].style.border ="2px solid red";
    } 
}
```

Or simply use `querySelector` (if there is only one element with that class)

```
var getEl = selector => document.querySelector( selector );
function passtrue(){
    var newpd = getEl('.newpd').value;
    var repeatpd = getEl('.repeatpd').value;
    if(newpd === repeatpd){
        getEl('.shine').style.border ="2px solid green";
    }else{
        getEl('.shine').style.border ="2px solid red";
    } 
}
```